# How to get the value from XML?

Tags: c#, xml

I'm making a small tool for checking the material number from the XML file.

I know this quite easy for you experts and I would like to ask for your help on this to get me started on this. On my machine I have .NET 2.0 framework I guess, and VS C# Express 2005 installed.

I have an XML that contains data of a material. It is located at my local drive. I am able now to browse the XML file and save the file in a string variable. Well, that's what I have done so far..

```
if(folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath, "Product.xml");

    string prodFile = files[0];
    ...
    ...
```

Suppose this is the structure of the XML:

```
<Record>
    <Product>
        <Material_Number>20209485</Material_Number> 
        <Product_Type>Type1</Product_Type>
        ...
        ...
    </Product>
</Record>
```

How can I get the material number value?

Comment: do you have this file alreaddy or do you want to use this style?

Comment: Just two small notes (that you may already know): Directory.GetFiles returns an *array* of file *names*, not the contents of a single file.

Comment: @Moonlight: I have the file already...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `XmlDocument` class for loading your XML File into a DOM.

> **MSDN** - This class implements the W3C Document Object Model (DOM) Level 1 Core and the Core DOM Level 2. The DOM is an in-memory (cache) tree representation of an XML document and enables the navigation and editing of this document. Because XmlDocument implements the IXPathNavigable interface it can also be used as the source document for the XslTransform class.

#### Sample

There are many ways to read your value. **I really encourage you to read [Working with Xml DOM](http://www.mastercsharp.com/Article/69/working-with-xml-dom)**

```
XmlNodeList list = xml.GetElementsByTagName("Product");
XmlAttributeCollection attr = list[0].Attributes;
string materialNumber = list[0].ChildNodes[0].InnerText;
```

or

```
XmlNodeList list  = xml.GetElementsByTagName("Material_Number"); 
string materialNumber = list[0].InnerText;
```

#### More Information

- [MSDN - XmlDocument Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx)
- [Working with Xml DOM](http://www.mastercsharp.com/Article/69/working-with-xml-dom)

Comment: I can't get how to fetch the value from the element.. But I understand the loading part from the example...

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `XPathNavigator` and `XPathExpression` with `XmlDocument`.

```
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load("Product.xml") //or xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlString);
var xmlNav = xmlDoc.CreateNavigator();
string materialNum;
var iterator = xmlNav.Select("/Record/Product/Material_Number");
if (iterator.MoveNext() && iterator.Current != null)
    materialNum = iterator.Current.Value;
```

---

If you use .Net 3.0+ you could use `System.Xml.Linq.XDocument`.

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load("Product.xml"); //or var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
var materialNum = xdoc.Root.Element("Product").Element("Material_Number").Value;
```

Comment: No he can't. XDocument is not supported in .NET 2.0

Comment: @dknaack Yep, sorry about that, just relalized now that he specified .Net 2.0

Comment: No problem. But you should update or delete your answer in order to prevent downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution. Not so elegant though...

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc= new XmlDocument(); 
xmlDoc.Load(@"C:\Product.xml");                 

XmlNodeList a = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Material_Number"); 
string materialNumber = a[0].InnerText;
```